# How to split a cell into key/value rows?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

```
Apple,3,Orange,4,Mango,10
```

How can I split this cell into key/value rows?

```
Apple (a1), 3(a2)
Orange (b1), 4(b2)
```

---

If I just call `split()`, I get:

```
Apple
3
Orange
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(ISNUMBER(SPLIT(A20, ",")), 
             SPLIT(A20, ",")&"♦", 
             SPLIT(A20, ","))), , 999^99)), "♦")), " ")))
```

[image: 0]